# How can I make LINQ Lambda expressions fail gracefully like XPath?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

More a general question, but how can I write LINQ Lambda expressions such that they will return a default string or simply an empty string if the LINQ expression fails or returns nothing. In XSLT XPath if a match fails then one just got nothing, and the application did not crash whereas in LINQ one seems to get exceptions.

I use First() and have tried FirstOrDefault().

So example queries may be:

```
Customers.First(c=>c.id==CustId).Tasks.ToList();
```

or

```
Customers.Where(c=>c.id==CustId).ToList();
```

or

```
Model.myCustomers.Where(c=>c.id==CustId);
```

etc.

Whatever the query, if it returns no records or null, then is there a general approach to ensure the query fails gracefully?

Thanks.

Comment: There really isn't a way unless you write your own extension methods. Null handling is just one of the most horrid things about most of today's languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't anything elegant built into C# for propagating nulls when you access properties. You could create your own extension methods:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static TValue SafeGet<TObject, TValue>(
        this TObject obj, 
        Func<TObject, TValue> propertyAccessor)
    {
        return obj == null ? default(TValue) : propertyAccessor(obj);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> OrEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
        return collection ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>();
    }
}
```

Used like this:

```
Customers.FirstOrDefault(c => c.id==CustId).SafeGet(c => c.Tasks).OrEmpty().ToList();
```

Comment: This looks very interesting. thanks. How would  "Model.myCustomers.First(c=>c.id==CustId).Name" look using your code?

Comment: `Model.myCustomers.FirstOrDefault(c => c.id == CustId).SafeGet(c => c.Name)`

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for, a generic approach to dealing with null lists and null values. Really appreciated your help thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`Customers.First(c=>c.id==CustId)` will crash if there is no matching record.

There are few ways you can try to find it, if you use `FirstOrDefault` that'll return `NULL` if no match is found and you can check for `NULL`.

Or, you can use the `.Any` syntax which checks if you have any record and returns `boolean`.

Comment: Thanks, Any() looks interesting.

Answer (score 0):

The only query I would expect to throw an exception would be the first one (assuming that `Customers` is a valid collection and not null itself):

```
Customers.First(c=>c.id==CustId).Tasks.ToList();
```

This will throw an exception if there is no customer with an `id` of `CustId` (you have some casing issues with your property and variable names).

If you don't wish to throw an exception on no match, then use `FirstOrDefault` as you mention, and do a null check, e.g:

```
var customer = Customers.FirstOrDefault(c => c.id == CustId);
if (customer == null)
{
    // deal with no match
    return;
}

var taskList = customer.Tasks.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. So you have to break the LINQ query up? I was hoping for a within expression approach.

Comment: You could use extension methods (or just plain old static helper methods) but it's likely you'll want to break up the code anyway as you're likely to wish to detect no matches and branch the code to invoke different presentation logic in your presentation layer.